# Android - How to listen for Bluetooth Pause / Play

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-bluetooth

I have a service that is playing a podcast.  I want the service to detect when the user presses pause or play from their BT radio so that I can stop and start it.  For the life of me I can't figure out what filter to add to my listener (myBroadcastReceiver is not getting called when I press a BT button).

```
IntentFilter intentFilters = new IntentFilter();
intentFilters.addAction(BluetoothHeadset.ACTION_AUDIO_STATE_CHANGED);
intentFilters.addAction(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);  
registerReceiver(myBroadcastReceiver, intentFilters);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you try android.intent.action.VOICE_COMMAND

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_VOICE_COMMAND

Also try setting your intent filter priority to some crazy high number in case some other app is canceling the broadcast.

Comment: Yeah tried that as well, still no luck.  My audio plays just fine, however when I press play on the BT device, both my podcast and the first song in my device's music playlist starts playing.

Comment: Set a high priority so your app get it first. And cancel the broadcast after you done with it so other app doesn't get it.

Comment: I really appreciate the suggestions @roostertech, however still no luck.  Can't believe there is not an example out there of a bluetooth receiver capturing the PLAY / PAUSE button.  I tried and see nothing with a  Log.v at the start of the receiver
        intentFilters.addAction(BluetoothHeadset.ACTION_AUDIO_STATE_CHANGED);
intentFilters.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND); 
intentFilters.setPriority(1000);